# ETL Pipeline Permission Denied, AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

New to AWS here, working in glue today to try and create a pipeline transferring json data in an s3 bucket into a PostgreSQL database.

For some reason, I keep getting this error:

"An error occurred while calling o185.pyWriteDynamicFrame. /run-1681506995039-part-r-00006 (Permission denied)"

Can't understand why - I'm using the visual editor and just connecting my bucket to a relational database via a mapping transform.

Script is auto generated...

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

# Script generated for node S3 bucket
S3bucket_node1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    format_options={"multiline": False},
    connection_type="s3",
    format="json",
    connection_options={"paths": ["s3://flightdatafinal2323"], "recurse": True},
    transformation_ctx="S3bucket_node1",
)

# Script generated for node ApplyMapping
ApplyMapping_node2 = ApplyMapping.apply(
    frame=S3bucket_node1,
    mappings=[
        ("flight_date", "string", "flight_date", "string"),
        ("flight_status", "string", "flight_status", "string"),
        ("`departure.airport`", "string", "`departure.airport`", "string"),
        ("`departure.timezone`", "string", "`departure.timezone`", "string"),
        ("`departure.iata`", "string", "`departure.iata`", "string"),
        ("`departure.icao`", "string", "`departure.icao`", "string"),
        ("`departure.terminal`", "string", "`departure.terminal`", "string"),
        ("`departure.gate`", "string", "`departure.gate`", "string"),
        ("`departure.scheduled`", "string", "`departure.scheduled`", "string"),
        ("`departure.estimated`", "string", "`departure.estimated`", "string"),
        ("`arrival.airport`", "string", "`arrival.airport`", "string"),
        ("`arrival.timezone`", "string", "`arrival.timezone`", "string"),
        ("`arrival.iata`", "string", "`arrival.iata`", "string"),
        ("`arrival.icao`", "string", "`arrival.icao`", "string"),
        ("`arrival.terminal`", "string", "`arrival.terminal`", "string"),
        ("`arrival.scheduled`", "string", "`arrival.scheduled`", "string"),
        ("`arrival.estimated`", "string", "`arrival.estimated`", "string"),
        ("airline", "string", "airline", "string"),
        ("`flight.number`", "string", "`flight.number`", "string"),
        ("`flight.iata`", "string", "`flight.iata`", "string"),
        ("`flight.icao`", "string", "`flight.icao`", "string"),
        (
            "`flight.codeshared.airline_name`",
            "string",
            "`flight.codeshared.airline_name`",
            "string",
        ),
        (
            "`flight.codeshared.airline_iata`",
            "string",
            "`flight.codeshared.airline_iata`",
            "string",
        ),
        (
            "`flight.codeshared.airline_icao`",
            "string",
            "`flight.codeshared.airline_icao`",
            "string",
        ),
        (
            "`flight.codeshared.flight_number`",
            "string",
            "`flight.codeshared.flight_number`",
            "string",
        ),
        (
            "`flight.codeshared.flight_iata`",
            "string",
            "`flight.codeshared.flight_iata`",
            "string",
        ),
        (
            "`flight.codeshared.flight_icao`",
            "string",
            "`flight.codeshared.flight_icao`",
            "string",
        ),
        ("destination", "string", "destination", "string"),
        ("country", "string", "country", "string"),
        ("arrival_airport", "string", "arrival_airport", "string"),
        ("schedule_arrive", "string", "schedule_arrive", "string"),
        ("temperature", "int", "temperature", "int"),
        ("description", "int", "description", "int"),
        ("wind_speed", "int", "wind_speed", "int"),
        ("wind_degree", "int", "wind_degree", "int"),
        ("humidity", "int", "humidity", "int"),
        ("feelslike", "int", "feelslike", "int"),
        ("visibility", "int", "visibility", "int"),
        ("cloud_cover", "int", "cloud_cover", "int"),
        ("`arrival.gate`", "string", "`arrival.gate`", "string"),
        ("`arrival.baggage`", "string", "`arrival.baggage`", "string"),
        ("`departure.delay`", "int", "`departure.delay`", "int"),
    ],
    transformation_ctx="ApplyMapping_node2",
)

# Script generated for node PostgreSQL table
PostgreSQLtable_node3 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    frame=ApplyMapping_node2,
    database="final",
    table_name="final",
    transformation_ctx="PostgreSQLtable_node3",
)

job.commit()
```